# Does having a foreground Service protect the entire process from being killed?

Tags: android, android-service

Is having a foreground service protective for the entire process? The documentation is a bit unclear, saying the service is highly unlikely to be killed. However, I've learned there's a big different between a service (or an activity) being destroyed versus the process (which contains all the activities and services, unless you are specifically forcing your service to be in a different process) being killed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: No, user can do anything if sufficient rights are there.

Answer (score 2):

First off, nothing prevents a process from being killed, and unfortunately there is very little you can do about it.  Android uses a modified form of Linux's "out of memory" process killer to periodically kill processes.  Memory does not even have to be low for a task to be killed - it can simply have been running for too long.  If you are root you can fiddle around with various files (under /sys or /proc, it's been a while since I have looked at this) in order to fight Android and try to keep a process from being killed, but unless you touch these files very rapidly (several times a second) Android will still likely to kill your process at an inopportune time.

Having a foreground service won't change any of this, it will merely bump your process to a higher priority so Android is more likely to kill other things first.  But depending on what else you are doing it may still have little effect.  For instance, I have a logger app which I wrote which takes 12-15MB of (non-shared) memory while running, and when foregrounded it still gets killed on a device with 512MB of RAM if I switch to (memory hungry) Firefox and do much of anything.  Note that there are things you can do to recover from this, for instance, telling AlarmManager to send you an intent periodically, which if your service is killed will restart it.  This will increase battery usage, however.

Now with regards to the Service itself versus the Activity class, Android can very well garbage collect your Activity after calling onPause without killing the process.  In this case, for example, if you have a pointer to your Activity from your Service class you will find that it is suddenly null, so if you are referring to your Activity in this way you should always test for a null pointer before trying to call into a non-static member of your Activity.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.  Only thing that seems dubious to me is that an activity can be GCed aftet on pause for several reasons. You are guaranteed to get an onStop call before an activity is killable after honeycomb (also onSaveInstance is invoked sometime before onPause and onStop if appropriate so that would also be defeated). More fundamentally though an activity is still visible after onPause so I'm not sure how it can be GCed. The rest is very useful though, thank you.

Comment: It also makes no sense for the pointer to suddenly be null that is not how GC works. I may prevent th e activity from being collected with such a pointer though it may have been destroyed (how many memory leaks happen). Generally unless the process itself is killed (in which case singletons and static variables are all reinitialized in which case you WILL get nulls) simple destruction of the activity should not cause that. At least i don't see how. Still i do null out the static ref to the activity onDestroy not to pressure memory further and it is unsafe for other reasons.

Comment: @Creos Yeah I'm not sure how to explain the null pointers, that is just from experience what I see.  I'm not sure if GC is the right word, you are right in that true GC would be expected to do the reverse of what is happening.